# Centre a overflowing element about its container

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have:

```
<div>
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>


div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
    width: 940px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

The iframe will overflow the div leading to a 'missing section' on the right. I need the Iframe centred such that this 'missing section' is the same both sides. Margin: 0 auto doesn't seem to cut it.

(The iframe is a video to put this into context)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a negative margin (as the half of the iframe *width*) as follows:

```css
iframe {
    width: 940px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -470px /* <-- 940px / 2 */
}
```

Or using `position: relative;` with `left: -470px;`.

`margin: 0 auto` will not work for the child which is wider than its parent. Even if you change the `display` property to `block`.

From the **[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth)** *(10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow)*:

> If `width` is not `auto` and `border-left-width` + `padding-left` +
>   `width` + `padding-right` + `border-right-width` (plus any of
>   `margin-left` or `margin-right` that are not `auto`) **is larger than
>   the width of the containing block**, then any `auto` values for
>   `margin-left` or `margin-right` are, for the following rules, treated
>   as **zero**.

If CSS3 is an option, you could set a *position* property for the `iframe` including a negative `translateX` to keep the element center when the *parent* resizes:

```css
iframe {
  width: 940px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;

  position: relative;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/novizegi/3/edit)**

For the old browsers which don't support CSS3 [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), you'll need to add an additional element as a wrapper.

In this approach, the *child* (`iframe` in your case) is wrapped by another element called `.wrapper` as follows:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.child {
  width: 940px;
  height: 300px;  
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/novizegi/4/edit)**.

Comment: Working beautifully to clip the edges of a running video

Answer (score 2):

Iframe is an inline element. Add `display: block;` to let `margin: 0 auto;` work.

Comment: I think `margin: auto` will not work for the child which is wider than its parent. In face, the `auto` is calculated as `0` in this case. Take a look at: http://jsbin.com/novizegi/1/edit

Comment: Not exectly, but yes, margin is counted as 0 in your example. But OP question was a bit different.

Comment: Yes apologies, I was actually using `display:block` but forgot to add it to the question. It doesn't work with overflowing content.