# How to center an img but only 1200px of 1920px?

Tags: html, css, image

I made an image of 1920px, but when I resize my window, I want my img to be centered but only 1200px of it (start at the very center, so 600px of the left and 600px of the right). I know margin:auto;, i know how to resize in % my image but how can I select only 1200px of it? Thx!!

Comment: Wrap the image by a `<div>` having `min-width: 1200px;` and `overflow: hidden` then use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881441/centre-a-overflowing-element-about-its-container/21881488#21881488) to achieve that.

Comment: Didn't really understand what you mean but try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/J85KN/11/). It centers the 1920px img and when you "resize your window" it centers only 1200px of that img. I didn't use the actual sizes since my screen isn't 1920px. You can play with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
img {
max-width: 1200px;
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly you should take a look at background positioning and media queries. Using the background image position property you can declare which part of the image you would like to show (i.e. 600px left and 600px right of center) when the screen is resized using a media query.  Here's a link to background-position - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position. Not sure how versed you're in media queries, if not you should look further into it.